# How to design entity in Jhipster jdl file for mongo db with complex data structure

Tags: java, mongodb, jhipster, jdl

I am new to **jhipster** and trying to use web application with **mongodb** as back end.

I have complex structure like class inside class in java representation or object inside object in JSON with arrays as well.

Please let me know if there is way to design entity in JDL studio for same.

I couldn't come across any example for the same.

Comment: same question, really... I have a Job object, which is supposed to have Amount object inside of it. the Amount is two fields: amount and currency. how to represent this embedded object in JDL?

Comment: I have the same question. Seems like there's no out of the box solution, I am going to code it myself.